# How to get a time format with Google Analytics add-on on google sheets

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to import from GA to google sheet with the add-on : 
ga:sessionDuration
ga:avgSessionDuration
and my problem is that my data are converted as number and so not with a time format...

Do you have any idea to convert it easily ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please provide some more details: Do you have an editor Add-on that you created to import data into Google Sheets? Did you write you Add-on with Apps Script? Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Units for ga:sessionDuration ga:avgSessionDuration defaults to seconds. If you want the units to be "x minutes and y seconds" or purely "minutes" then you can write a formula in another cell to convert. If you want the data in a "time format" like 12:00pm, then understand that you are really looking for a time stamp, not session duration.